# change the jquery code from old version to new version

Tags: javascript, jquery, codepen

Good morning i found this js that i would like to use, but i saw that the jquery version it's old (2.1.3) and if i add a new version (3.6) of the jquery it doesn't work.

How i can change the code to make it work? Here the code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#preloader').velocity({
                opacity : 0.1,
                translateY: "-80px"
            }, {
                duration: 400,
                complete: function(){
                $('#hola').velocity({
                translateY : "-100%"
            }, {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: [0.7,0,0.3,1],
                complete: function(){
                    $('.home').addClass('animate-border divide');
                }
            })  
                }
            })
        },1000)
    })
```

Here you can see the link to a codepen: https://codepen.io/uavide/pen/qBoaadr
Many thanks
Davide

I found the problem and i changed so now it works with jquery version 3.6

```
 $(window).on('load', function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
```

but now the problem it's with velocity that it doesn't work with the version 2.0.6 (but it work with the version 1.2.3.) and i don't understand why, just the animation it stops after the loader finish to load and it doesn't open the page.

Comment: See: [jQuery Upgrade Guides](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/)

Comment: Thanks i found the solution i change this: $(window).load(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){      with this: $(window).on('load', function () {
            setTimeout(function(){  now i have another problem, velocity deosn't work properly if ia use the version 2..i can't understand why... it ry to expalin over..i edit my post

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: Velocity doesn't support transform since version 2.0 (WTF)...
So you have to add like css

Here the code that it works with jquery 3.6 and velocity 2.0.6

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#preloader')
      .velocity(
        {
          opacity : 0.1,
          transform: ["translateY(-100px)", "translateY(0px)"]
        },
        {
          duration: 400,
          complete: function() {
            $('#hola')
              .velocity(
                {
                  transform: ["translateY(-100%)", "translateY(0px)"]
                }, 
                {
                  duration: 1000,
                  easing: [0.7, 0, 0.3, 1],
                  complete: function() {
                    $('.home').addClass('animate-border divide');
                  }
                }
              )  
          }
        }
       )
   },1000)
})
```